# How to dynamically add values to a table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I implemented the function to create a table and add a value when I enter the current data.

Here is the code:
HTML:

```
<div class="firstDate" style="margin-left: 35px;" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input type="date" id="firstDate" onchange="checkTodayDate(this)" name="ri_startDate">
</div>

<div class="secondDate" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input type="date" id="secondDate" onchange="checkTodayDate2(this)" name="ri_endDate">                  
</div>

<div class="hospitalTime" style="margin-top: 12px;/* padding: 3px; */margn-left: 5px;margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 5px;" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input type="text" style="width: 195px;" name="ri_chozyinTime"  id="ri_chozyinTime">                    
</div>

<div class="hospitalTime" style="margin-top: 12px;/* padding: 3px; */margn-left: 5px;margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 5px;" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input type="text" style="width: 195px;" name="ri_zaezyinTime" id="ri_zaezyinTime">                 
</div>

<div class="table-responsive dataZone" style="margin-top:30px">
    <table class="table" data-role="table" id="table-column-toggle" data-mode="columntoggle" style="display:none">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-priority="1">First Date</th>
                <th data-priority="2">Second Date</th>
                <th data-priority="3">First Medical</th>
                <th data-priority="4">Second Medical</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
        </table>
        <div style="display:none" class="submitGo">
            <input class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Submit" type="submit">
        </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function AddScore()
    {
        $('#table-column-toggle').show();
        $('.submitGo').show();
        var jqTableBody = $('#table-column-toggle tbody');
        var sTRTemplate = 
        '<tr>' + 
        '    <td>{firstDate}</td>' +
        '    <td>{secondDate}</td>' +
        '    <td>{chozyin}</td>' +
        '    <td>{zaezyin}</td>' +
        '</tr>';

        var sTRAppend = sTRTemplate;

        $('div[data-role="fieldcontain"] > input').each(function(){
            switch(this.id) 
            {
              case 'firstDate' : sTRAppend = sTRAppend.replace('{firstDate}', this.value); break;
              case 'secondDate' : sTRAppend = sTRAppend.replace('{secondDate}', this.value); break;
              case 'ri_chozyinTime' :  sTRAppend = sTRAppend.replace('{chozyin}', this.value); break;
              case 'ri_zaezyinTime' : sTRAppend = sTRAppend.replace('{zaezyin}', this.value); break;
            }
          });
```

If you enter a value and press the Add button, it is implemented to create a row.

What I would like to do in the future is,

If the `firstDate` and `secondDate` values are the same, if you enter a value and click the Add button, you do not create a new row.

The picture below is shown.

[image]

How do I implement what I want to implement?

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how.

Comment: What will set in `firstDate` and `secondDate`? I mean what they will return?

Comment: Nothing is returned. If you enter a new value and click the Add button, you do not want to create a new row when firstDate and secondDate are equal to the previously added value, but you want to add a value to the existing row.

Comment: I don't get it, correct me if am wrong. There is some input, and user enter some entry to them, if `firstDate` and `secondDate` wasn't the same, you let to create new row otherwise you wont let, right?